# Optimize a keyword

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, silktest, silk

I automate tests using SilkTest and Java.
In this keyword, I get the list and I compare it to the one expected.
Is there a way to optimize my code since I have declared each list multiple times.

```java
public void vérification_des_listes(String listAttendu) {
    final String[] list1 = listAttendu.split(";", -1);
    final ArrayList<String> listExpected = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final String I : list1) {
        listExpected.add(I);
    }
    System.out.println(listExpected.toString());
    final Object[] list2 = desktop.<DomListBox>find("BrowserApplication.BrowserWindow.Personne.Titre_champ").getItems().toArray();
    final ArrayList<String> listFound = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Object E : list2) {
        listFound.add(E.toString());
    }
    System.out.println(listFound.toString());
    assertTrue("", listExpected.equals(listFound));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public static void vérification_des_listes(String listAttendu) {
    final String[] list1 = listAttendu.split(";", -1);
    final List<String> listExpected = Arrays.asList(list1);


    final Object[] list2 = desktop.<DomListBox>find("BrowserApplication.BrowserWindow.Personne.Titre_champ").getItems().toArray();

    final List<String> listFound = Arrays.stream(list2).map(Objects::toString).toList();

     Assertions.assertEquals(listExpected, listFound);
  }
```

You can take advantage of class Arrays, and also do some java stream processing for converting your objects to String. Also take a look at assertj to compare Collections in a more flexible way (can see an example [here](https://mkyong.com/junit5/junit-5-assertj-examples/)).

Comment: Thank you for your help ! i only had to chage this line `final List<String> listFound = Arrays.stream(list2).map(Objects::toString).toList(); ` since it presented an error to `final Stream<String> listF = Arrays.stream(list2).map(Objects::toString); final List<String> listFound = listF.collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 final String[] list1 = listAttendu.split(";", -1);
 final ArrayList<String> listExpected = new ArrayList<>();
 for (final String I : list1) {
     listExpected.add(I);
 }
```

you could use

```
final String[] list1 = listAttendu.split(";", -1);
final List<String> listExpected = Arrays.asList(list1);
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)